# Passenger error Web application could not be started - Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rubygems, passenger

I have set up an Ubuntu server in VirtualBox according to the instruction in 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4'.  I'm at the point of running my application in a production environment.  I installed ruby 1.9.3 using RVM, transferred my code to the server, ran bundle install, started rails server, and verified that I can run the application at localhost:3000.  All went well.  The application ran as expected.  I shut down rails server, successfully installed Passenger (had to satisfy 4 missing header files on the first go) and created the needed apache2 configuration files (one in sites-available and one in conf.d).  If I run bundle install and rails server at this point all is well.  However, when I shut down rails server and attempt to access the site through apache I get a passenger error -  Web application could not be started  - Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources.  I've checked.  i18n (0.6.1) is in gemfile.lock and the in same directory as the other gems - /home/gene/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@CMS/gems/i18n-0.6.1 (from $bundle show).  The application still runs under rails server. Where do I start to unravel this error?

Comment: Let's check your environment. Can you verify that your application is being started by Phusion Passenger as the `gene` user? Can you also check whether the Ruby interpreter that Phusion Passenger is using to start your app, is the same as the one that you expect, i.e. ruby-1.9.3-p448@CMS?

Comment: Can you please paste your apache config file?